# Conditional hidden tag based on checkbox condition in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I send a hidden tag based on whether or not a checkbox is checked?

I have a table with a product title and product price and check box selection on each row and on the form submit I'd like to send both of these values to a controller. I was only able to get one value to submit with a single checkbox, so I added a hidden tag field, however, this hidden tag will submit every row, which is not what I want. In the params sent example below it should have two items and two prices sent, but it sends all the prices for each row. (As an aside, if there is a better way to send both params without using a hidden tag please let me know!)

This is data from a google analytics API report request FYI =>

```
@product_revenue.reports[0].data.rows
p.dimensions[0] = "Product Title"
p.metrics[0].values[0] = "Product Price"
```

The structure of this comes from [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/AnalyticsreportingV4/AnalyticsReportingService).

[image: Table Image]

View Code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <%= form_tag add_multiple_path, method: :post do %>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th><strong>Product Title</strong></th>
      <th><strong>Product Price</strong></th>
      <th><strong>Add?</strong></th>
    </thead>
    <% @product_revenue.reports[0].data.rows.each do |p| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= p.dimensions[0] %></td>
        <td><%= p.metrics[0].values[0] %></td>
        <td>
          <%= check_box_tag 'price_test_datum[product_title][]', p.dimensions[0] %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag('price_test_datum[product_price][]', p.metrics[0].values[0]) %>
        </td> 
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
  <%= submit_tag "Add selected" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The hidden field is dumping all of the column values instead of the one associated with that row?

Parameters sent:

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"token here", 
  "price_test_datum"=>{
    "product_price"=>["29.98", "14.99", "14.99", "14.99", "14.99", "14.99", "299.95", "35.97", "21.98", "10.99", "33.98", "27.98", "13.99", "59.99", "29.98", "59.98", "29.99", "110.93", "4088.79"], 
    "product_title"=>["Turquoise Bracelets", "Red Bracelets"]
  }, 
  "commit"=>"Add selected"
}
```

Comment: Please show a portion of the `@product_revenue` data...

Comment: This `'price_test_datum[product_price][]'` looks funky - in particular the trailing `[]`. `'price_test_datum[product_price]` seems like it should do the trick. I don't think that's your problem, but it looks weird.

Comment: Added that data and included image of table

Comment: Also, it's odd that your view code has `<th><strong>Product Price</strong></th>`, but your pasted image says "Product Revenue". Are you sure you're editing the right file?

Comment: I'm trying to structure the params so that params[:price_test_datum][:product_price] = product price and params[:price_test_datum][:product_title] = product title. Haven't gotten that part figured out yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I added an index to the table loop and used the checkbox value to submit the relevant row value (index) to the controller. I then used hidden tag fields to send all the product title and price values in as arrays to the controller and used the row key to find the relevant value. This seems like an inelegant solution, but it worked.

```
<%= form_tag add_multiple_path, method: :post do %>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th><strong>Product Title</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Product Price</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Add?</strong></th>
  </thead>
  <% @product_revenue.reports[0].data.rows.each_with_index do |p, index| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= p.dimensions[0] %></td>
      <td><%= p.metrics[0].values[0] %></td>
      <td>
        <%= check_box_tag 'row[]', index %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag 'price_test_datum[product_title][]', p.dimensions[0] %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag 'price_test_datum[product_price][]', p.metrics[0].values[0] %>
      </td> 
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Controller Code

```
def add_multiple
params[:row].each do |r|
  PriceTestDatum.create(product_title: params[:price_test_datum][:product_title][r.to_i],
                        product_price: params[:price_test_datum][:product_price][r.to_i])
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to price_test_data_path }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end
```